# How to use Firebase's onAuthStateChanged to track user login state in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have set up a user login flow with Firebase and am now trying to guard pages from being accessed when a user is not logged in. From the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users), I am aware that I can track user log in state with `onAuthStateChanged`, but I am not sure what to include in that function that would allow me to identify whether a user is logged in from a route guard. How can you keep track of the login state with `onAuthStateChanged`?

Edit:

To be more specific, I am not sure how to direct the router when `onAuthStateChanged` is called. I tried making a call to an injected Router

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        this.router.navigate('home');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate('login');
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

but when `onAuthStateChanged` is called, I get an error stating that `this.router` is undefined.

Comment: API documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#onauthstatechanged

Comment: Your question should be more like "not able to access global variable inside nested function(ie. function inside function)" and solution will be use arrow function inside function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realized that the problem is a scoping issue with the anonymous function. Using the `=>` syntax fixes the problem.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.router.navigate('home');
      } else {
        this.router.navigate('login');
      } 
    });
  }
}
```